# How to revert the build in Teamcity after the CI tests failed

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I am using TeamCity for my CI integration and TFS as my code repo. We trigger a build to deploy the code changes on every check-in by devs. Once this build is successful, then we trigger another build configuration which runs some sanity tests which are managed by automation team and not the unit tests. Now when any test in this build fails, I want to revert the check-in made by the dev's implying there was a problem in the application with the latest code and previously successful build to be redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use TC Delayed Commit Feature.

- [Delayed Commit Overview Page](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html)
- [Delayed Commit Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Pre-Tested+(Delayed)+Commit)